# Por que os Traits podem ter métodos chamados diretamente quando estes são estáticos?

Tags: php, trait

Acabei de fazer um questionamento sobre `Traits` e me veio uma outra dúvida.

Se os `Traits` são mecanismos que facilitam a importação de métodos, por conta das limitações de um herança no PHP, por que podem os seus métodos serem acessados estaticamente?

Por exemplo:

```
trait Stack
{
    protected $items = [];

    public static function say()
    {
        return 'stack';
    }

}

echo Stack::say(); // stack
```

Isso não fica confuso tendo em vista o sentido da implementação do `trait` na linguagem?

É recomendado o uso de um método estático vindo de um `trait`, ou é melhor utilizá-lo numa classe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após dar uma lida [neste site](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php), eu entendi o seguinte:

1. Membros (campos e/ou métodos) vindos de um `trait` tem uma prioridade maior que os vindos de uma super classe, mas menor que os da classe atual.
2. Quando duas classes diferentes usam o mesmo `trait`, membros estáticos do `trait` são diferentes para cada uma das classes.

E tem outras coisas mais sobre `traits` no site linkado, se tiver mais dúvidas.